# User defined command inside a section title. xstring and bookmark (hyperref) involved

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, strings, xstring

I'm trying to define a command to "centralize" the titles of some sections (that are used in more places inside the document). So I thought that creating a command with a number as argument (the number of the item) which would return the title text for that number would be useful.
I was working fine until I remembered to add bookmarks/`hyperref` to the mix.

Here is a MWE describing the situation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xstring} %To test conditions with strings and such.

\usepackage{bookmark}

%If the argument is 1 it will return "y ¡Ya no puedo más!", etc.
\newcommand{\UnasPalabras}[1]{
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{y ¡Ya no puedo más!}%
        {2}{Siempre se repite esta misma historia.}%
        {3}{¡Melancolíiiiiiiía!}%
    }[Horror!]%
}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \section{Siempre me voy a enamorar}
    De quien de mi no se enamora,\newline
    es por eso que mi alma llora.

    \section{\protect\UnasPalabras{1}}
    \UnasPalabras{1}
    \UnasPalabras{2}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to circunvent this situation and use a command that will return a string associated with a number when using it in a section title with `hyperref`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The commands in `xstring` are not expandable, so they don't work in PDF bookmarks. If you're testing integers only, try `\newcommand{\UnasPalabras}[1]{\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax\or y ¡Ya no puedo más!\or Siempre se repite esta misma historia.\or ¡Melancolíiiiiiiía!\else Horror!\fi}`

Comment: It works!

Long time since I write here. How can I select your comment as the right answer?
Thanks a lot btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the commands in the `xstring` package don't work in expansion-only contexts. One example of this is in PDF bookmarks of section headers.

If you are testing integers only, instead of `xstring` you can use `xparse` and the `\int_case:nnF` `expl3` function. The first argument of `\int_case:nnF` is the number to test, the second is, as in `\IfEqCase` a list of pairs `{<number>}{<text>}`, and the third argument is used in case no match was found.

`expl3` also has `\str_case:nn(T|F|TF)` functions for strings, if your input is not integers only. This command is also expandable.

I defined a wrapper `\IntCasennF` around `\int_case:nnF` so that you can use it in non-`expl3` code. Here's a working example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,titlepage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse} % To do all kinds of cool macros in TeX
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \IntCasennF { m m m }
  { \int_case:nnF {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{bookmark}

%If the argument is 1 it will return "y ¡Ya no puedo más!", etc.
\newcommand{\UnasPalabras}[1]{%
    \IntCasennF{#1}{%
        {1}{y ¡Ya no puedo más!}%
        {2}{Siempre se repite esta misma historia.}%
        {3}{¡Melancolíiiiiiiía!}%
    }{Horror!}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Siempre me voy a enamorar}
De quien de mi no se enamora,\newline
es por eso que mi alma llora.

\section{\protect\UnasPalabras{1}}
\UnasPalabras{1}
\UnasPalabras{2}

\end{document}
```

A more brute-force (and much less robust) way would be using the TeX `\ifcase` primitive:

```latex
\newcommand{\UnasPalabras}[1]{%
  \ifcase\numexpr#1\relax
    \or y ¡Ya no puedo más!%
    \or Siempre se repite esta misma historia.%
    \or ¡Melancolíiiiiiiía!%
    \else Horror!%
    \fi
}
```

however I wouldn't recommend this one because it will break more easily with bad input.